# Who is Luke speaking to in the Force Awakens teaser?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In a teaser trailer released several months ago for *The Force Awakens*, we hear the following monologue in Luke’s voice:

> *"The Force is strong in my family.  My father has it.  I have it. My sister has it.  **You have that power, too.**"*

This resembles a portion of dialogue between Luke and Leia in *Return of the Jedi*, but the *"You have that power, too"* part marks this out as new (and not simply a re-use of a sound clip from *Return* — at least not totally).

However, we now know that this monologue does not actually appear in the theatrical release of *The Force Awakens*.

**Who is Luke speaking to?**

I suppose the obvious candidate is

> Rey,

but is there any official comment to this effect?

Comment: It could also be his nephew, Ben, early in his training, before he went dark. It'd be odd in normal conversation to say "my sister" instead of "your mother", so that part would have to be a spoiler-dodging contortion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Probably the person in your spoiler block, if anyone, but we don’t know for sure.**

First, note that the final sentence isn’t new. It’s just some dialogue from *Return of the Jedi*, but slightly rearranged. This is what Luke says to Leia:

> You're wrong, Leia. You have that power too. In time you'll learn to 
>   use it as I have. The Force is strong in my family. My father has 
>   it… I have it… and… my sister has it.

See [this YouTube clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MDYX_PgorRY#t=1m35s) from *Return of the Jedi*.

It’s been rearranged to put more emphasis on Luke’s family first, and build up to the implication that there’s a new Force sensitive.  I couldn’t find an interview with the producers that confirmed who this was supposed to refer to (perhaps nobody in particular, just the general implication).

But let’s also consider this line from Maz Kanata in the main trailer:

> The Force. It’s calling you… let it in.

This does appear in the movie, and we know who it’s directed to. It seems reasonable to assume the line from the teaser is referring to the same person.

Comment: and considering the "power" she did in the movie...