# Doesn't the 2nd "The Force Awakens" trailer imply that Rey is related to Luke?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, luke-skywalker

In the [2nd teaser trailer for The Force Awakens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngElkyQ6Rhs), from 0:33 to 1:00 we hear Luke say:

> The Force is strong in ***my family***. My father has it. I have it. My sister has it. ***You have that power too***.

The only person he could be referring to with "You have that power too" is Rey, so this strongly implies that she is also part of "my family" (Luke's family).

If that weren't enough, the shot at 0:53 also seems to show Maz Kanata handing Luke's light saber to Rey shortly before "You have that power too".

Se also [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112240/58598).

Given this, I'm surprised that there's still so much doubt about whether Rey is a Skywalker. What have I missed?

UPDATE: Yes, I know that that dialogue is a mix from the scene in Jedi where Luke tells Leia they are brother and sister, and that it doesn't appear in The Force Awakens. However, IMO that doesn't reduce its significance.

Comment: “The only person he could be referring to with "You have that power too" is Rey” — could be Snoke, bro.

Comment: “What have I missed?” The difference in meaning between the words “implication” and “fact”?

Comment: [Never trust a trailer.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NeverTrustATrailer)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite when something is strongly implied, that usually doesn't leave much room for doubt. Everyone seems to think that Rey being a Skywalker or not is about 50/50.

Comment: Here's what we know: touching Anakin's lightsaber gave Rey some sort of flashback to a bunch of scenes involving Skywalkers.  Rey is Force-sensitive, which is known to be passed down by heredity.  Rey's father disappeared, and Luke Skywalker went into exile.  Rey was supposed to find her long-lost father on an island, which is where she found Luke.  And Daisy Ridley bears a strong resemblance to young Natalie Portman.  These are the facts; feel free to draw conclusions from them. ;-)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - my money is on Jar-Jar

Comment: The sentences taken together need not involve Luke talking to someone in his family. He could just be establishing bona fides in terms of his ability to tell that she's strong in the force. "My family are very artistic. I can tell you're very artistic too." So that (combined with the line not being in TFA) is the wiggle room. That said, everything about that trailer, from playing the music closely associated with Luke to using a desert planet we were all supposed to think was Tatooine, is clearly an attempt to generate this kind of interest and speculation. Which is what a trailer is for. :-)

Comment: @mluisbrown - I used to think Rey was his child till I read the film script. The way he reacts to her in a script is... well, don't know how to put it, but it's just TOTALLY not how I would expect a father to react to a daughter he hasn't seen for 15 years. Doesn't prove much, but I'm now far less sure

Comment: @mluisbrown: “when something is strongly implied, that usually doesn't leave much room for doubt”. Well, that depends on who’s implying it, and why. The filmmakers could totally intend for people to draw the conclusion that Rey and Luke are related because that’s what they’re planning, or they could intend for us to draw that conclusion because that’s *not* what they’re planning, and they want to surprise us. For what little it’s worth, 50/50 sounds about right to me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It could be a flashback to Luke's early training of Kylo Ren, before he turned to the dark side. Since Ren is certainly part of Luke's family, being his nephew, it would be a perfectly reasonable thing for Luke to say.

Comment: It's mixed dialogue of Luke revealing to Leia he is her brother from ROTJ. Since it's only present in the trailer, I think it was more setting the scene/reminding people of the past, than giving any clues.

Comment: @JohnBell Wait, do you really think they didn't mean to give away hints?

Comment: It's plausible that "you" is referring to Kylo Ren, but IMO that's unlikely, especially given the accompanying imagery.

Comment: @mluisbrown If it really is about Kylo, then they couldn't have used clearer imagery, because that would spoil who Kylo is.

Answer (score 4):

If you read [here](http://www.bustle.com/articles/76892-is-luke-skywalker-narrating-the-star-wars-episode-vii-trailer-fans-might-recognize-the-ominous-quote) it actually explains it is an amalgamation of dialogue taken from a scene in the original trilogy in which Luke reveals to Leia he is her brother, and since it isn't repeated in the actual film, it's pure speculation as to why it is included in the trailer. Only time will tell whether this is relevant to Rey or not.

Comment: Yes, I know that it's a mix of dialogue from Return of the Jedi. That doesn't reduce its significance. It could be that Luke will still say those words in Episode 8 or 9.

Comment: Still, that is conjecture. I'm giving facts here, and the only facts we have is it is a mix of dialogue from previous films. The significance of it is purely up to your own judgement unless something changes in the future. I didn't say it wasn't significant or otherwise.